# How do I disable zypper's certificate check?

Tags: ssl, certificates, sles, zypper

I'm using SLES 2015 behind a firewall. All of my outgoing communications go over a proxy; specifically, zypper tries to use the proxy when I write, say,

```
zypper search-packages foo
```

but the proxy provides its own SSL certificate instead of the actual target site, essentially running a "man in the middle" attack :-P  ... and so I get:

```
SSL verification failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
Certificate issuer: /C=US/O=Foo Inc./CN=Foo Inc. External Root CA 2.1
Certificate subject: /C=US/O=Foo Inc./OU=Whatever/CN=Foo Inc. CA 2.1
Could not search for the package: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

I want to avoid this failing certificate verification; and I'm guessing the easiest way is to just not verify any certs. How do I turn the verification off?

**Additional info:**

```
# zypper repos
Warning: No repositories defined.
Use the 'zypper addrepo' command to add one or more repositories.
```

Comment: According to https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_manual_%28plain%29, you might use ssl_verify=no in repo URI.

Comment: @AlexBaranowski: There are no repo files in `/etc/zypp/repos.d`... where do I put that `ssl_verify=no`?

Comment: Can you include following output: `zypper repos` and then `zypper repos failing_repo_name` ?

Comment: @AlexBaranowski: See edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add the option `ssl_verify=no` to the `baseurl` parameter.
So if you do not want to check the URL of the offical sources you can use:

```
# WARNING: Use this option only if you know what you do
baseurl=https://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/15.2/repo/oss/?ssl_verify=no
```

Comment: No longer experiencing this issue, but I think this did the trick